# MYSQL - Return query A or query B, but not both. If both exist return result of query A

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT phone_number
  , 3
  , 3
  , toppings
  , crust
FROM pizza p
INNER JOIN lemon l ON p.seven_digit = l.code
UNION
SELECT phone_number
  , 3
  , 3
  , toppings
  , crust
FROM pizza p
INNER JOIN lemon l ON p.six_digit = l.code;
```

As you can see it's:
query A INNER JOIN subtable UNION query B INNER JOIN subtable

I want the results of query A or query B but not both. If both exist return A's results.

l.code in this example has 6 or 7 digit numbers.

Right now I'm getting double the results.

**UPDATE**

So I'll help make a better description:

```
CREATE TABLE not_on_lrn_table_3_22 (
  phone_number bigint NOT NULL,
  seven_digit int DEFAULT NULL,
  six_digit int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (phone_number)
)
CREATE TABLE lerg (
  code int NOT NULL,
  status varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL
)
INSERT INTO not_on_lrn_table_3_22
VALUES
(2222226433, 2222226, 222222),
(2222222222, 2222222, 222222),
(2222263445, 2222263, 222226),
(2222283445, 2222283, 222228);
INSERT INTO lerg
VALUES
(222222, 'AAA'), (2222226, 'BBB'), (2222223, 'CCC'), (2222281, 'DDD'),
(2222263, 'EEE')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YmSY.png)

I want a result for each row in not_on_lrn_table_3_22 (if there's a match).

For example,
Lerg code column is either 6/7 digits long.
I want to look at not_on_lrn_table_3_22 first row, look for its seven_digit value and try to match on *lerg.code* If it's there, return that row of data, if it's not there check the six_digit column against *lerg.code* If it's there, return that row, if it's not there skip that row.

The idea is that 7 digit code matches are more accurate.

A solution provided to me was:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
       SELECT pn.*, l.*
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pn.phone_number
                                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.code = pn.seven_digit
                                               THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS ord
         FROM not_on_lrn_table_3_22 AS pn
         JOIN lerg AS l
           ON l.code IN (pn.six_digit, pn.seven_digit)
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1
 WHERE ord = 1
;
```

It works, but it takes forever to complete.

Here's another image explaining what I'm trying to achieve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmskZ.png)

Look at first row:
there's a match for code/status in 6/7th column (six digit) so i would return data associated with lerg's table where the code = 222222.

2nd row:
there's 2 matches. code/status in 4/5/6/7th column. (seven digit & six digit). When it matches both, return data associated with lerg's table where the code is 2222226. (Because it's more digits and thus more accurate).

3rd row:
1 match in 4/5th column. Again because this is 7 digits you'd simply do the same on 2nd row.

4th row:
no matches, so nothing should be returned.

Comment: Please list a sample of the desired results.

Comment: Can you give an example? @Isildur

Comment: @kerafyrmkerafyrm See my updated answer below which I think is simpler and build of off you attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how big of an improvement this will be, but give it a try

```
select phone_number, coalesce(seven_digit,six_digit), coalesce(l2.status,l.status)
from not_on_lrn_table_3_22 as pn
left join lerg as l on l.code =pn.six_digit
left join lerg as l2 on l2.code=pn.seven_digit
where coalesce(l2.status,l.status) is not null;
```

Comment: Yes. That's basically what i want, but the only problem is that I had other columns on the lerg table not listed on here, and so i get the error: `Column 'state' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: So ultimately my query looks like such: `select phone_number, 3, 3, state, carrier, number_type, gmt AS time_zone_offset, coalesce(seven_digit,six_digit), coalesce(l2.status,l.status) from not_on_lrn_table_3_22 as pn left join lerg as l on l.code =pn.six_digit left join lerg as l2 on l2.code=pn.seven_digit where coalesce(l2.status,l.status) is not null`.

Comment: @kerafyrmkerafyrm You need to use the table alias in the column names e.g. t.state instead of state

Comment: Do i just add a coalesce to each field? ie., coalesce(l.state, l2.state) ?

Comment: Yes that should do it. `coalsece` return the first non null value. So if you have a preference for value of one column over another, order them correctly inside `coalesce`

Comment: AWESOME! I think this works. Going to add it to main code. Thank you so much!

Comment: @kerafyrmkerafyrm Great! Please remember to accept/upvote the answer if it helped solve the problem.

Comment: It's saying I don't have enough rep points to do so. I'll be sure to follow up it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `phone_number` comes from table `lemon` (although you haven't specified which column belongs to `lemon`, I assume there is at least one column from `lemon` in SELECT clause, otherwise UNION would combine identical rows and you would not get any duplicates):

```
SELECT 
  phone_number, 
  3, 
  3, 
  toppings, 
  crust 
FROM
(
SELECT 
    if(l1.phone_number is null, l2.phone_number, l1.phone_number) as phone_number
  , toppings
  , crust
FROM pizza p
LEFT JOIN lemon l1 ON p.seven_digit = l1.code
LEFT JOIN lemon l2 ON p.six_digit = l2.code
)
t
WHERE phone_number is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phone_number
  , 3 some_alias
  , 3 another_alias
  , toppings
  , crust
FROM pizza p
INNER JOIN lemon l ON p.seven_digit = l.code
WHERE LENGTH(l.code) = 7
UNION ALL
SELECT phone_number
  , 3
  , 3
  , toppings
  , crust
FROM pizza p
INNER JOIN lemon l ON p.six_digit = l.code
WHERE LENGTH(l.code) = 6
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM pizza p
                  INNER JOIN lemon l ON p.seven_digit = l.code
                  WHERE LENGTH(l.code) = 7)
```

If you want to minimize the amount of work performed by the server, create and use a stored procedure instead of a single query.